# Pandas columns to list using groupBy

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

Simple data-frame and I want to generate lists using GroupBy.

[image]

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Name': ["David","David","David","David","Kate","Kate","Kate","Kate","Kate","Kate"], 
'Truck' :     ["PLO8318","PLO6372","PLO6473","PLO8249","PLO6540","PLO7623","PLO8036","PLO6314","PLO7791","PLO7848"],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_1 = df.groupby('Name')['Truck'].apply(list)
df_1 = df_1.to_frame().reset_index()

for index, row in df_1.iterrows():
    print (row['Name'], row['Truck'])
```

Output:

```
('David', ['PLO8318', 'PLO6372', 'PLO6473', 'PLO8249'])
('Kate', ['PLO6540', 'PLO7623', 'PLO8036', 'PLO6314', 'PLO7791', 'PLO7848'])
```

How can I have print-out like:

```
David = ['PLO8318', 'PLO6372', 'PLO6473', 'PLO8249']
Kate = ['PLO6540', 'PLO7623', 'PLO8036', 'PLO6314', 'PLO7791', 'PLO7848']
```

Comment: `for index, row in df_1.iterrows(): print (row['Name'],'=', row['Truck'])`?

Comment: @Quang Hoang, just there are too many quotation marks. :)

Comment: print exactly what you ask for on my jupyter notebook.

Comment: um, not in Sublime Text. what should I do...?

Comment: It works just fine the way @QuangHoang presented and I used vim to write a python script and then ran it in the terminal. Maybe it is a problem with the python version? What's yours? Mine is 3.7.6.

Comment: Python 2.7.15. I tried it with basic IDE, it's also showing "('David', '=', ['PLO8318', 'PLO6372', 'PLO6473', 'PLO8249'])"

Comment: @Quang Hoang, can you post it as an answer?